# Edit Item button on SharePoint Server 2016 list takes user to blank page

Tags: list, 2016, edit

I am using a SharePoint 2016 list at work - we have a list that multiple users can contribute to. They are in a Group that all have the same permission. One person creates new list items, and the users have to go in and click on Edit Item and respond to the item.

ONE user continues to have issues with editing. When she goes into the item and clicks Edit Item, it just takes her to an almost blank page - it still shows the headers and side column, but it does not take her into edit mode of that particular item. I have no idea what the problem is and nobody else has reported this issue.

Has anyone experienced this or does anyone know of a solution? She has to keep asking coworkers to complete the items for her and it's getting old.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It could be the problem with list experience setting. In order to fix this issue, please follow the below steps :

- Go to the **List Setting page - > Click on Advanced Settings**
- Navigate to "**List Experience**" at the bottom and select **Classic Experience** option.
- Click OK button
- Refresh the list URL page
- Test the list item edit page

This is how blank page issue will get resolved.

**Approach 2**

If the above troubleshooting doesn't fix the issue, we may look into the below :

- Opera the list "EditForm.aspx" page in SharePoint 2013  designer.
- Once the editform.aspx opens up, double click on the web part and a property popup window opens up
- Expand “Layout” and Unselect “Close the web part”

[Layout and Unselect “Close the web part](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/TNBlogsFS/BlogFileStorage/blogs_technet/manjesh/WindowsLiveWriter/Gettingablankpagewhileeditinganyitemonal_28E7/2.jpg)

MSDN article source :

[Getting a blank page while editing any item on a list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-in/archive/blogs/manjesh/getting-a-blank-page-while-editing-any-item-on-a-list)

Comment: Hi - thanks for your response. Do all SharePoint lists have a "List Experience"? I did see this on another article and when I go to Advanced Settings I don't see any List Experience. I also don't have enough permission to do anything to the EditForm.aspx, I think this is done by our admin since it is through work.